# NullPointerException with HereMaps SDK V3.10.x

Tags: android, here-api

I recently updated my HereMaps SDK from v3.3.x to 3.10.x and after updating I am not getting any maneuvers, TTA and Distance to Next maneuver.

While Calling methods `NavigationManager.getInstance().getTta(Route.TrafficPenaltyMode.OPTIMAL, true).getDuration()`

AND

```
NavigationManager.getInstance().getDestinationDistance()
```

I am getting

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.here.android.mpa.routing.RouteTta.getDuration()' on a null object reference

I am getting this NullPointer with both of the methods above. Additionally No callbacks for maneuvers and the Distance Left.

Can anybody put a light on what might be happening here? As everything was fine before SDK update.

Comment: It seems the NavigationManager is not in the navigation mode. What ist the error code that is returned from NavigationManager.startNavigation function?

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport I am calling the methods above only when Navigation is started, How I can print the error code? I am using try/catch blocks for printing the stack trace.

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport One more important point to note that everything is working fine in simulation mode but not when doing normal test using GPS. PS. I have tried using app with different devices and all are behaving the same.

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport I have checked my error code, Which is `Error.NONE` also I have made sure that my maneuver instruction listeners  have a strong reference to the object so that it wont get garbage collected. but still I am getting same error. The reference code for Maneuver's demonstration is been REMOVED from the github repo. of Here-SDK examples of android.

Comment: Please check if you start PositioningManager before navigation is started?
PositioningManager.getInstance().start(LocationMethod.LOCATION_METHOD_GPS)

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport Yes, I am doing it on `onEngineInitializationCompleted` callback. After the callback I am doing navigation and other stuff.

Comment: Could you please provide sample code/app that reproduces the issue?

Answer (score 0):

With the latest SDK it is essential to ensure that the map data is loaded onto the device before Navigation is started, otherwise the SDK may go into an invalid state, which seems like the issue here. 
There are interfaces available to implement loading pf the map data onto the device, namely MapDataPrefetcher and MapLoader.

From Documentation : https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/map-data.html

> Some key functionality offered through HERE SDK depends on HERE Map
>   Data being downloaded and cached on the device. Rendering a map on the
>   screen, for example, is not possible without first downloading map
>   data to the device. Similarly, it would not be possible to provide
>   accurate turn-by-turn navigation without downloading map data to the
>   device.